# How to hide fields based on values of a selection field in another module

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have a custom model `budget.budget`. There is a selection field `od_term`. There is another model `budget.line` which has some fields that need to be displayed based on the value of `od_term`.
For example if `od_term` is monthly the lines should display only `od_m1` field. if `od_term` is `quart` then `od_q1` need to be displayed.

Comment: Can you please share your code here for which you want to add this?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.       I solved the issue by using related field